# PHP MAIL: Send 2 Different Emails to 2 Different Recipients

Tags: php, email

I need to take a form with 3-4 fields and have the info sent to two different emails, with different info.

EXAMPLE:

```
FIELD ONE: NAME
FIELD TWO: EMAIL
FIELD THREE: COMMENT
```

(When submitted)

```
EMAIL ONE: JUST FIELD THREE IS SENT
EMAIL TWO: ALL THREE FIELDS ARE SENT
```

I tried the following:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  // The message 
  $name = $_POST['name']; 
  $email = $_POST['email']; 
  $comment = $_POST['comment']; 

  $msg1 = $comment; 

  $msg2 = $name."\n\n".$email."\n\n".$comment; 

  // Send 
  mail('emailone@whatever.com', 'My Subject', $msg1); 
  mail('emailtwo@whatever.com', 'My Subject', $msg2); 
} 

?> 

<html> 
<head> 
<title>Test</title> 
</head> 

<body> 
<form name="frmemail" action="" method="post"> 
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p> 
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p> 
<p>Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea></p> 
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p> 
</form> 
</body> 

</html>
```

This works, but the strange thing is:

emailone@whatever.com received **both** `EMAIL ONE` and `EMAIL TWO` (when it is supposed to receive EMAIL ONE only).

emailtwo@whatever.com received EMAIL TWO only (which what I want).

Can someone tell me why emailone@whatever.com received **both** `EMAIL ONE` and `EMAIL TWO`?

I tested using gmail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There does not appear to be anything wrong with your code. Is the actual code same is this? is `emailtwo@whatever.com` set to forward emails to `emailone@whatever.com`?

Comment: Oh yes, its because I had set emailtwo@whatever.com to forward to emailone@whatever.com, but I forgotten about it. So the code does work correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it's sending 2 emails, it's because:

- You are calling the mail() function twice
- Your To: header specifies two addresses, or
- Your MTA is configured to copy someone automatically.

The most probable reason is you are calling mail() twice. You can check this using your apache/IIS logs.